# How do I get Spyder to display on the relevant output?

Tags: python, spyder

When I open up spyder the console is immediately filled with text like this without me executing anything and when I actually run a script it adds tons more of this:

[image: spyder print]

‌how do I stop that from displaying? I guess I turned it on somehow but I have no idea how. Its kind of a nightmare to have to sort through all the junk to get to the information I need to see. Can anyone help?

Comment: No clue what setting you changed in order to produce this verbose startup, wouldn't it be easiest to just reinstall spyder and ipython? You can try this from the command line `python -c "from spyderlib.spyder import main; main()" --reset`

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) This looks like debug output that shouldn't appear in the console at all. Please look for directories called `.ipython` and/or `.jupyter` in your `Users` directory and remove them. That should fix your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I got that "UserWarning: Parent poll failed" message for a while whenever I opened my Spyder. I did not get your other messages.

I got rid of my message when I uninstalled Anaconda Python then installed the latest version, namely the December 2018 version which has the filename `Anaconda3-2018.12-Windows-x86_64.exe`. The message is now gone and I got Spyder version 3.3.2. When I first ran Spyder I got notices to upgrade to the latest version of Spyder, version 3.3.3. Conda does not yet have that version but it probably will very soon.

Note that after I uninstalled Anaconda Python and before I installed the latest version, I checked my `C:Users` directory and deleted the folders `.conda`, `.ipyton`, `.matplotlib`, `spyder-py3`, and any other Python-related folder. (Hat-tip to @CarlosCordoba for a reminder of this step.) This step has helped remove some problems for me in the past.

If you do not want to be that drastic, try running the "Reset Spyder settings" command that should be in your menu structure. That did not remove my message but it may remove some of yours.